# redirect a subdir simplycreate.online/zephyr-guide/ instead of zephyr-guide.simplycreate.online

Tags: redirect, apache2

i setup github pages successfully...

on my hoster cpanel i setup subdomain

[cpanel entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iElKE.png)

then in github pages settings.... i add Custom domain: zephyr-guide.simplycreate.online

however simplycreate.online/zephyr-guide/ is not displaying the github pages

if i do a .htaccess 301 redirect it redirects to the subdomain. i dont want that i want the user to remain on simplycreate.online/zephyr-guide/

EDIT: i put the following in htaccess but it still redirects over to the secondary domain:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} simplycreate\.online  [NC]
RewriteRule ^zephyr-guide/(.*)  https://zephyr-guide.simplycreate.online/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

I adopted a github actions script to ftp the contents into the shared hoster. i believe this actually was the simplest method, silly me complicating with redirects...